# Condition in ifelse: Value in multiple columns/variables

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, operators, conditional-statements

This might be an easy one:

I like to create the condition "*value in variableB or variableA*".

What works is this:

`var1 %in% c("value1", "value2")` condition: var1 is value1 or value2

`var2 | var3 %in% 1` condition: var1 is 1 or var2 is 1 (var1 and var2 are dummies with 0/1)

With these I can get around the repetitive code:

```
var1 == "value1" | var1 == "value2"
```

and

```
var2 == 1 | var3 == 1
```

what I am looking to replace is

```
var4 == "value1" | var5 == "value1"
```

Reproducible example:

(I leave out var1-var3)

```
var4 <- c("value1", "valuex")
var5 <- c("valuey", "value1")

df <- data.frame(var4, var5)
```

I use case_when() from the dplyr package but it should work with the base R ifelse as well.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(newvar= case_when( CONDITION HERE ~ "value1", 
                     TRUE~"else"))
```

if in var1 or var2 there is value1, the new variable should be value1

(First question on stackoverflow. Sorry for any unclarity.)

Comment: Are you looking forward to create a column or `filter` the rows?

Comment: `var2 | var3 %in% 1` is not doing what you think it does, test  `3 | 2 %in% 1`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Just coming from Stata where one can do `gen asean4 = 1 if inlist(countryname, “Indonesia”, “Malaysia”, “Philippines”, “Thailand”)` but also flip that around `gen thai = 1 if inlist(“Thailand”, country1, country2, country3)`. Was looking for something similar.

Comment: I am looking for a condition in an if-else statement. Something that gets rid of the repetitive `== "value1` in `var4 == "value1" | var5 == "value1`.

Comment: back to this `var2 | var3 %in% 1` It seems to work for numeric variables or I am missing something: `q1_a <- c(1,0,0) 
q1_b <- c(0,1,0)
test <- data.frame(q1_a, q1_b)
test$q1_a | test$q1_b %in% 1` gives out `> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE` which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var4 == "value1" | var5 == "value1"` is equivalent to `any(c(var4,var5)=="value1")`

Inside a data.frame you could do this:

```
df$new_col <- apply(df[,c("var4","var5")] == "value1",1,any)
```

Comment: `any(c(var4,var5)=="value1")` does not work for me. `df <- df %>% mutate(newvar= case_when( any(c(var4,var5)=="value1") ~ "value1", 
                     TRUE~"else"))` and newar is else for both cases.

Comment: In your mutate statement var4 and var5 are vectors, so the c statement just concatenate every value, my first option works with single strings. That's why I gave you a second option for where you're dealing with columns. If you include the expected output in your question we'll be able to help better.

Comment: I must have overlooked the second option and the possibility to include the part before the assignment in the ifelse. That second option works with `df <- df %>% mutate(newvar= case_when( apply(df[,c("var4","var5")] == "value1",1,any) ~ "value1", TRUE~"else"))` Thanks a lot, will save some unnecessary code work!

Answer (score 6):

If we need to check whether 'value1' is present in any one of the columns in each row, use the `filter_all` with `any_vars`

```
df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. =="value1"))
```

For a specific subset of columns, use the `filter_at`

```
df %>%
   filter_at(vars(matches("var\\d+")), any_vars(.== "value1"))
```

---

For creating a binary column based on multiple column comparison, use the `mutate_at` (or `mutate_all` if all columns needs to be compared), `reduce` it to a single logical/integer vector and bind it as a column to create the new column in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("var\\d+")), funs(.=="value1")) %>% 
  reduce(`|`) %>%
  as.integer %>%
  bind_cols(df, new_var = .)
```

---

Or as @Nick mentioned in the comments, we can use `across` (`dplyr` version `>1.0.0`) instead of the deprecated `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(matches("var\\d+"), ~!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, how do I get the `mutate_at` code to work when my `funs` is `!is.na`?

Comment: @CharlotteJelleyman  `funs` is now deprecated.  Now, it should be `list(~ !is.na(.)))`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, but how do I incorporate `list(~ !is.na(.)))` into the rest of the above code? I get an error when I run the `reduce('|')` line. `Error in Ops.POSIXt(.x, .y) : '|' not defined for "POSIXt" objects`

Comment: @CharlotteJelleyman  It is difficult to answer without a small reproducible example using `dput`.  I would suggest to post a question

Comment: OK, I thought it would be simple since I think I want to do exactly as you have described in your answer "For creating a binary column based on multiple column comparison..." except that newvar = 1 if !is.na in a selection of columns. Am working with exported Survey Monkey data which is horrible!

Comment: @CharlotteJelleyman  I understand your issue, but this was answered more than a year ago and there are differences in syntax with the new tidyverse along with the fact that it is difficult to debug an error without a small repro example.  Otherwise, we can talk about these for more time and it wouldn't help you either

Comment: New tidyverse syntax: ```mutate(across(matches("var\\d+"), ~!is.na(.))) %>%```